# Trouble wih bundle exec rake install

Tags: command-line, mysql, postgresql, database, ruby-on-rails

I am getting this rake aborted message after running bundle exec rake install command for git repository project I am working on.This is the code of trace of operations and error message.

```
/home/vihang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:463:in `exec'
/home/vihang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/home/vihang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/home/vihang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
/home/vihang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
/home/vihang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
/home/vihang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
/home/vihang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/vihang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in `with_friendly_errors'
/home/vihang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vihang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/vihang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => dashboard:setup_db => seed:default => seed:scripts => seed:custom_levels


rake aborted!
'RAILS_ENV=development RACK_ENV=development bundle exec rake dashboard:setup_db --trace' returned 1


/home/vihang/code-dot-org/lib/cdo/rake_utils.rb:115:in `system_stream_output'
/home/vihang/code-dot-org/lib/cdo/rake_utils.rb:100:in `rake_stream_output'
/home/vihang/code-dot-org/lib/rake/install.rake:51:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/vihang/code-dot-org/lib/rake/install.rake:43:in `chdir'
/home/vihang/code-dot-org/lib/rake/install.rake:43:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/vihang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/vihang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => install => install:all => install:dashboard

``
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @David **20.10**